# Searching a ListBox with duplicates

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a ListBox which is adding text every time a client sends a message to the server.

I want too search the ListBox to look for duplicates and output a message.

For example if the ListBox is as follows:

```
Cat
Dog
Rat
```

Nothing should happen.

However if the ListBox is as follows:

```
Cat
Cat
Dog
```

I want it to clear or output a message.

Any Ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071951/best-algorithm-for-delete-duplicates-in-array-of-strings

Comment: Maybe not the most efficient way but you could create a method that adds each item in the list box to an array list but before each item is entered in to the array list check that the item is not already present in said array list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple implementation to get you started:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < listBox1.Items.Count; j++)
            {
                if (listBox1.Items[i].ToString() == listBox1.Items[j].ToString())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Duplicate {0}:{1}", listBox1.Items[i].ToString(), listBox1.Items[j].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

From your example listbox items, the output of the above code will produce:

```
"Duplicate Cat:Cat"
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help but this one worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you switch to a `HashSet`?

So you put everything in a `HashSet` and then you put all elements into the `ListBox`.

```
HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>();
```

A HashSet contains always unique elements.

If I do this:

```
hashSet.Add("Hello");
hashSet.Add("Hello");
```

the `hashSet` will contain "Hello" just once.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this ?

```
var duplicates = myListBox.Items.Cast<string>().Where(i => i.Count() > 1);
if (duplicates.Any()) 
   // Duplicates
   Console.WriteLine("Alert !"); 
else 
   myListBox.Items.Add(myString);
```

Comment: You can use : myListBox.Items.Cast<string>().Where(i => i.Count() > 1);