# Fastest way to remove duplicates of a sorted Go slice

Tags: sorting, go, duplicates

```golang
    mySlice := make([]uint32, 0, 4294967290)

// ...

        // Sort the slice
        sort.Slice(mySlice, func(i, j int) bool {
            x := mySlice[i]
            y := mySlice[j]
            return x < y
        })
```

What's the fastest way to remove slice duplicates?

How can I take advantage of the fact that slice is already sorted?

## Update

I came up with this:

```golang
func RemoveDuplicates(s []uint32) {
    if len(s) < 2 {
        return
    }
    tmp := make([]uint32, 0, len(s))

    for i := uint32(0); i < uint32(len(s)); i++ {
        // If current is not equal to next then store the current
        if s[i] != s[i+1] {
            tmp = append(tmp, s[i])
        }
    }

    // The last must be stored
    // Note that if it was repeated, the duplicates are NOT stored before
    tmp = append(tmp, s[len(s)-1])

    // Modify original slice
    s = nil
    s = append(s, tmp...)
}
```

Any mistake? Any bug? Any way to improve?

## Update

As noted by @mh-cbon the correct loop max should be `i < uint32(len(s)) - 1`:

```golang
for i := uint32(0); i < uint32(len(s)) - 1; i++ {
```

Comment: If the slice is sorted, duplicate elements must be next to each other. So when searching for duplicates, you only have to compare neighbors. Please include what you've tried and what problems you have.

Comment: the post lacks reproducible examples and stuff like that https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Right, I understand. I was just looking for ideas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

not an answer as to the fastest, rather a step by step about the methodology to apply using the Go language to optimize a piece of code.

For a very formal insight of what is the fastest, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6072100/4466350

Your code is buggy. Always write a test.

First, let use write a main

```golang
package main

import (
    "math/rand"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
}

func randSlice(max int) (ret []uint32) {
    // we should check that max does not exceed maxUINT32
    ret = make([]uint32, 0, max)
    r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(99))
    for i := 0; i < max; i++ {
        ret = append(ret, uint32(r.Intn(max)))
    }
    sort.Slice(ret, func(i, j int) bool {
        return ret[i] < ret[j]
    })
    return
}

func dedup1(s []uint32) []uint32 {
    if len(s) < 2 {
        return s
    }
    tmp := make([]uint32, 0, len(s))

    for i := uint32(0); i < uint32(len(s)); i++ {
        // If current is not equal to next then store the current
        if s[i] != s[i+1] {
            tmp = append(tmp, s[i])
        }
    }

    // The last must be stored
    // Note that if it was repeated, the duplicates are NOT stored before
    tmp = append(tmp, s[len(s)-1])

    // Modify original slice
    s = nil
    s = append(s, tmp...)
    return s
}
```

And the accompanying test

```golang
package main

import "testing"

func TestDedup1(t *testing.T) {
    s := randSlice(10)
    res := dedup1(s)
    uniq := map[uint32]bool{}
    for _, r := range res {
        _, ok := uniq[r]
        if ok {
            t.Fatalf("found duplicates\ninput=%#v\nresult=%#v\n", s, res)
        }
        uniq[r] = true
    }
}
```

running this we get

```
$ go test -v . 
=== RUN   TestDedup1
--- FAIL: TestDedup1 (0.00s)
panic: runtime error: index out of range [10] with length 10 [recovered]
    panic: runtime error: index out of range [10] with length 10

goroutine 18 [running]:
testing.tRunner.func1.1(0x536680, 0xc0000da040)
    /home/mh-cbon/.gvm/gos/go1.15.2/src/testing/testing.go:1076 +0x30d
testing.tRunner.func1(0xc000082600)
    /home/mh-cbon/.gvm/gos/go1.15.2/src/testing/testing.go:1079 +0x41a
panic(0x536680, 0xc0000da040)
    /home/mh-cbon/.gvm/gos/go1.15.2/src/runtime/panic.go:969 +0x175
test/d/dup.dedup1(0xc000094060, 0xa, 0xa, 0xa, 0x6124a0, 0xc00003c770)
    /home/mh-cbon/gow/src/test/d/dup/main.go:32 +0x248
test/d/dup.TestDedup1(0xc000082600)
    /home/mh-cbon/gow/src/test/d/dup/main_test.go:7 +0x70
testing.tRunner(0xc000082600, 0x54fbf0)
    /home/mh-cbon/.gvm/gos/go1.15.2/src/testing/testing.go:1127 +0xef
created by testing.(*T).Run
    /home/mh-cbon/.gvm/gos/go1.15.2/src/testing/testing.go:1178 +0x386
FAIL    test/d/dup  0.006s
FAIL
```

we fix this by appropriately checking for the slice bounds.

In `dedup1`, change this condition `if s[i] != s[i+1] {` to `if i+1 < uint32(len(s)) && s[i] != s[i+1] {`, or even better, reduce iteration max value by one `for i := uint32(0); i < uint32(len(s))-1; i++ {`

Next, write a function to generate a slice with random duplicates.

```golang
func randSliceWithDups(max int) (ret []uint32) {
    ret = randSlice(max / 2)
    ret = append(ret, ret...)
    sort.Slice(ret, func(i, j int) bool {
        return ret[i] < ret[j]
    })
    return
}
```

writing `randSliceWithDups(50)` get slices such as `[0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9 9 9 12 12 13 13 18 18 18 18 18 18 19 19 20 20 20 20 21 21 22 22 24 24]`

update the tests again

```golang
func TestDedup1_with_dups(t *testing.T) {
    s := randSliceWithDups(10)
    res := dedup1(s)
    uniq := map[uint32]bool{}
    for _, r := range res {
        _, ok := uniq[r]
        if ok {
            t.Fatalf("found duplicates\ninput=%#v\nresult=%#v\n", s, res)
        }
        uniq[r] = true
    }
}
```

Next, add a benchmark; It will help us spot performance issue and maintain performance over time.

```golang
func BenchmarkDedup1_1000(b *testing.B) {
    s := randSliceWithDups(100)
    b.ResetTimer()
    b.ReportAllocs()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = dedup1(s)
    }
}
```

running this  we get :

```
$ go test -v . -bench=.
=== RUN   TestDedup1
--- PASS: TestDedup1 (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestDedup1_with_dups
--- PASS: TestDedup1_with_dups (0.00s)
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: test/d/dup
BenchmarkDedup1_1000
BenchmarkDedup1_1000-4        172087          6353 ns/op        5504 B/op          2 allocs/op
PASS
ok      test/d/dup  1.174s
```

Let us state the obvious every one has spotted reading your initial code without even writing a benchmark, you are allocating.

That raises the question as to figure out if you are allowed to modify the input slice in place or not. If you can change it in place, we might take advantage of this to prevent that allocations and speed up your program.

One solution, wrote from scratch (consider search on geekforgeeks like website for a generally accepted solution), is to iterate over the slice and maintain an index of the next position to write. When a non duplicate is found, save the non duplicate to this last position, then increment that index by one. Finally, return the slice up to the value of the incremented indice.

```golang
func dedup2(s []uint32) []uint32 {
    if len(s) < 2 {
        return s
    }

    var e int
    for i := 1; i < len(s); i++ {
        if s[i] == s[i-1] {
            continue
        }
        s[e] = s[i]
        e++
    }

    return s[:e]
}
```

Again, add tests and benchs, and check for the result.

```golang
func TestDedup2(t *testing.T) {
    s := randSlice(10)
    res := dedup2(s)
    uniq := map[uint32]bool{}
    for _, r := range res {
        _, ok := uniq[r]
        if ok {
            t.Fatalf("found duplicates\ninput=%#v\nresult=%#v\n", s, res)
        }
        uniq[r] = true
    }
}

func TestDedup2_with_dups(t *testing.T) {
    s := randSliceWithDups(10)
    res := dedup2(s)
    uniq := map[uint32]bool{}
    for _, r := range res {
        _, ok := uniq[r]
        if ok {
            t.Fatalf("found duplicates\ninput=%#v\nresult=%#v\n", s, res)
        }
        uniq[r] = true
    }
}

func BenchmarkDedup2_1000(b *testing.B) {
    s := randSliceWithDups(100)
    b.ResetTimer()
    b.ReportAllocs()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = dedup2(s)
    }
}
```

Which yields:

```
$ go test -v . -bench=.
=== RUN   TestDedup1
--- PASS: TestDedup1 (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestDedup1_with_dups
--- PASS: TestDedup1_with_dups (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestDedup2
--- PASS: TestDedup2 (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestDedup2_with_dups
--- PASS: TestDedup2_with_dups (0.00s)
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: test/d/dup
BenchmarkDedup1_1000
BenchmarkDedup1_1000-4       1764574           673 ns/op         544 B/op          2 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup2_1000
BenchmarkDedup2_1000-4       7758907           152 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      test/d/dup  3.224s
```

a 4x improvement ! cool ! What s next ? Next is to find an even better algorithm which produces less executions, less lookup and so on.

Though, the last version contains a bug ! Have you spot it ?

See this test, which is better than the other because it does not rely on random numbers, but on static values with strong equality checks. Using those kind of tests you can tailor made your input to check for fine grained situation.

```golang
func TestDedup2_static(t *testing.T) {
    type expectation struct {
        input []uint32
        want  []uint32
    }

    expectations := []expectation{
        expectation{
            input: []uint32{0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5},
            want:  []uint32{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
        },
        expectation{
            input: []uint32{0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5},
            want:  []uint32{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
        },
    }

    for _, e := range expectations {
        res := dedup2(e.input)
        if !reflect.DeepEqual(res, e.want) {
            t.Fatalf("invlaid result, wanted=%#v\ngot=%#v\n", e.want, res)
        }
    }
}
```

It uses table drive testing as described at https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/09/writing-table-driven-tests-in-go

Lets fix this:

```golang
func dedup2(s []uint32) []uint32 {
    if len(s) < 2 {
        return s
    }

    var e int = 1
    for i := 1; i < len(s); i++ {
        if s[i] == s[i-1] {
            continue
        }
        s[e] = s[i]
        e++
    }

    return s[:e]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To remove duplicate elements of a slice you can create a map and assign the the slice values as keys of the map ,then iterate over the map and append the key values to the new slice.Here is the code for the same logic:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func removeDupe(slc []int) []int {
    var tmpSlice []int
    chkMap := make(map[int]bool)

    for _, val := range slc {
        chkMap[val] = true
    }

    for k, _ := range chkMap {
        tmpSlice = append(tmpSlice, k)
    }
    sort.Ints(tmpSlice)
    return tmpSlice
}

func main() {

    mySlice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 9, 0}
    formattedSlice := removeDupe(mySlice)

    fmt.Println(formattedSlice)

}
```

Output:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 9]
```

Comment: Did you do any performance benchmark? Is your approach faster or the other approach suggested? Not sure.

Comment: I am not familiar with benchmarks,but the above method is most prevalently used for removing duplicates in slice

Answer (score 0):

What about the following generic approach, this works on any comparable type and simply checks if the item is already in the map, if it's not it assumes it's unique and adds it to our final array.

This avoids the approach above of iterating over two arrays, in this way we only iterate over one.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func RemoveDuplicates[T comparable](slice []T) []T {
    itemMap := make(map[T]bool, len(slice))
    items := make([]T, 0)
    for _, item := range slice {
        if _, ok := itemMap[item]; !ok {
            items = append(items, item)
            itemMap[item] = true
        }
    }
    return items
}

func main() {
    duplicateStr := []string{"a", "a", "b", "c"}
    dedupeStr := RemoveDuplicates(duplicateStr)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", dedupeStr)

    duplicateInts := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2}
    dedupeInts := RemoveDuplicates(duplicateInts)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", dedupeInts)
}
```

This keeps the order of the array.

```
[a b c]
[0 1 2 3]
```

Golang Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/9Y8AHe2AkIM

If you want to deduplicate an array of pointers you can do it as long as each object pointed to implements .String() method.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Stringer interface {
    String() string
}

// Remove all duplicate objects in an array of pointers
func RemoveDuplicateStringers[T Stringer](slice []*T) []*T {
    itemMap := make(map[string]*T)
    items := make([]*T, 0)
    for _, item := range slice {
        if item != nil {
            key := (*item).String()
            if _, ok := itemMap[key]; !ok {
                itemMap[key] = item
                items = append(items, item)
            }
        }
    }
    return items
}

func main() {
    // Use net.IP as a reference
    ip1 := net.ParseIP("1.1.1.1")
    ip2 := net.ParseIP("1.0.0.1")
    ip3 := net.ParseIP("1.1.1.1")
    ip4 := net.ParseIP("1.2.3.4")
    ip5 := net.ParseIP("1.1.1.1")
    ip6 := net.ParseIP("1.0.0.1")
    ip7 := net.ParseIP("1.2.3.4")
    duplicates := []*net.IP{&ip1, &ip2, &ip3, &ip4, &ip5, &ip6, &ip7}
    dedupe := RemoveDuplicateStringers(duplicates)
    fmt.Printf("%s", dedupe)
}
```

Here the order of the array is also kept

```
[1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 1.2.3.4]
```

Goland Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/Q5yr_2FxQ_H